# sending hex and binary data through serial

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider this function which construct a packet and sends it to can bus via usb serial:

```
def _write_to_can(id, data):
  num_bytes=len(data)
  send_buf = bytearray([0xAA,0xE0|num_bytes,])
  for byte in reversed(id):
      send_buf.append(byte)
  for byte in data:
      send_buf.append(byte)
  send_buf.append(0x55)
  print(send_buf)
  #serial.write(send_buf)
```

And these two simple test inputs:

```
_write_to_can(bytes.fromhex("1F 01 10 51"),  bytes.fromhex("85 15 08 01"))
_write_to_can([0x1F,0x01,0x10,0x51], [0x85,0x15,0x08,0x01])
```

Which if run (python3), seem to output identical byte arrays (at least so it looks to me):

```
bytearray(b'\xaa\xe4Q\x10\x01\x1f\x85\x15\x08\x01U')
bytearray(b'\xaa\xe4Q\x10\x01\x1f\x85\x15\x08\x01U')
```

But only the first one works - and the device on the other end responds, while with the second one nothing happens. I'm new to python and whole serial binary hex thing, so I must be making some very stupid mistake?

Comment: They *are* equivalent.  Assign the results to variables and compare them and the result is `True`.  The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: But nothing else is different. I just comment one or the other out, and it works ... or it doesn't...

Comment: Can't help without some way to reproduce the issue.  The data shown is equivalent.  Are you sure you can send that same command twice in a row to the receiver with no issues?

Comment: In fact, `serial.write(b'\xaa\xe4Q\x10\x01\x1f\x85\x15\x08\x01U')` should work as well as either example.

Comment: This command sets my HRV unit to auto mode. So if it succeeds, I reset it to manual and try again. One option is that this cheap chinese CAN adapter is broken, but then probability theory is playing dirty tricks on me, cause it always (like 5 out of 5) works with fromhex, but always fails with array. But you are right, these are identical structures

Comment: You should definitely take a look at the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module, which should be able to prepare the output in one shot instead of requiring byte-wise feeding. Also your `reversed(id)` is most probably an endianness issue, which can be configured centrally.